# React - How do i force child components to re render when parent state component changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

in my pen http://codepen.io/seunlanlege/pen/PbYNor?editors=0010#0

what's happening is pretty simple. when the `this.send()` method is called. `this.state.chat` is sent to child component `<Messages /> which is then concatenated to the`this.state.messages` array and rendered.

but the thing is, 1second after rendering i update `this.state.sent` which is a prop of `<Messages />` but messages component doesn't re-render.

please how do i force it to re-render?

```
class Messages extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
}
render(){
return(
`<p id={this.props.key} className={this.props.style}>{this.props.msg}<span>{this.props.sent}</span></p>`);
}
}


class Chat extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.count = 0;
    this.state = {chat :'',messages:[],sent:[]}; 
}
chatChange(event){
    this.setState({chat : event.target.value});
}
send(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let x = this.state.messages;
    this.setState({messages:x.concat([<Messages style="me" msg={this.state.chat} key={this.state.chat} sent={(this.state.sent[this.count])?this.state.sent[this.count]:''} />])});
this.setState({chat:''});
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.setState({sent:this.state.sent.concat(['sent'])});
  this.count++;
},1000);
}
render () {
    return(
        `<div>
        <div id="top"><h1>Chat With Customer Support</h1></div>
        <div id="chatbox">
        {this.state.messages}
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
        <form onSubmit={this.send.bind(this)}>
        <span>
        <input value={this.state.chat} type="text" onChange={this.chatChange.bind(this)} id="chat" value={this.state.chat} />
        <button type="submit" id="send">Send</button>
        </span>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>`
        );
}
}ReactDOM.render(<Chat name="seun" />,document.getElementById('app')):</code>
```

Comment: The message box is indeed updating the problem here is that when you submit the same text it won't update coz React sees the change as the already existing element in the virtual DOM of messages. what you should do is add an id to each message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your codepen is alomost fine, only thing you missed is proper key for message component,

for react to render components properly each component should have different key, so i changed the piece of code from

```
<Messages style="me" msg={this.state.chat} key={this.state.chat} sent={(this.state.sent[this.count])?this.state.sent[this.count]:''} />
```

To

```
<Messages style="me" msg={this.state.chat} key={this.count} sent={(this.state.sent[this.count])?this.state.sent[this.count]:''} />
```

and code-pen worked fine

EDIT 
this solves the propblem

instead of saving the components to state, dynamically build them. check this codepen.io/abhirathore2006/pen/JbjjPx

Comment: but when `this.state.sent` is modified `<Message />` component does not re-render

Comment: instead of saving the components to state, dynamically build them. check this  http://codepen.io/abhirathore2006/pen/JbjjPx

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a key for  component

```
 this.state.messages.length
```

React won't allow you to enter two elements with the same key. This is how the react virtual DOM diffs the changes on re-render

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps should take nextProps.

Comment: could you please fork my pen outlining the correct way to do this?

Comment: http://codepen.io/petronii29/pen/YpKdYY?editors=0010#0 Usually we use setState in componentWillReceiveProps.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the whole component rerenders, React matches all the components with the previous state/key. So if you give a unique key to the child on every time parent rerenders, the child will also re-render.

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) provides a function [_.uniqueId()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqueId) that generates a unique id every time it is called.

```
<Parent>
    <Child key={_.uniqueId('child_component')} />
</Parent>
```